# ShareKit bug - Expected Expression

Tags: sharekit

I'm getting an odd share kit 2.0 bug when I add it to my existing project. I've been looking a t this for a while now, and haven't really got anywhere.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you walk through the code, you can find any bug manually but this is time consuming.
So, please delete the whole ShareKit 2.0 first by removing real files.

And re-download the kit again and install it again!

This might rectify your problem.

I hope this helps you.